# What exactly does server name do in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I kind of understand that once you are accessing nginx say via localhost, the exact server that is matched is determined by the port and the server_name which is the request "Host" header. But what exactly does server_name do besides that? Or is that the only function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this is the only function.